# Postfix - Dovecot | Mail received in the logs but nothing in my mails on the client

Tags: email, smtp, imap, postfix-mta, dovecot

Good morning,

I recently installed a Postfix Dovecot mail server on my server, the sending of mail works well, but when I receive it, in the logs /var/log/mail.log I see that the mail coming from outside has arrived, but when I update the received mails (in imap) on my Thunderbird client, nothing new...

```
May 21 16:59:16 mail postfix/smtpd[12020]: CB2B55C07FF: client=mail-vs1-f42.google.com[209.85.217.42]
May 21 16:59:16 mail postfix/cleanup[12025]: CB2B55C07FF: message-id=<CAJPq62KN159jCO=aKBoLMRgnEvVS++JPdMZubhHswgUpay1HMQ@mail.gmail.com>
May 21 16:59:16 mail postfix/qmgr[11985]: CB2B55C07FF: from=<quentin.****@gmail.com>, size=4653, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 21 16:59:17 mail postfix/local[12026]: CB2B55C07FF: to=<quentin@****.fr>, relay=local, delay=0.25, delays=0.23/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
May 21 16:59:17 mail postfix/qmgr[11985]: CB2B55C07FF: removed
May 21 16:59:17 mail postfix/smtpd[12020]: disconnect from mail-vs1-f42.google.com[209.85.217.42] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mua_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mua_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
mua_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mydestination = $myhostname, ****.fr, mail.****.fr, localhost.****.fr, localhost
myhostname = mail.****.fr
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = ****.fr
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org, permit
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_restriction_classes = mua_sender_restrictions, mua_client_restrictions, mua_helo_restrictions
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.****.fr/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.****.fr/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

For information, the mails arrive well in the folder /home/quentin/Maildir
So I think it's just a dovecot configuration problem but I don't know where if it's the case...

Do you have any idea where the problem might be coming from?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In this file:

```
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
```

I changed that setting

```
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
```

for

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

Problem solved :D